# In a Jenkins shared library infrastructure, how do I import class in another file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm using [Jenkins shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) plugin and have the following structure

```
src/com/domain/service/baseClass.groovy
          "           /subClass.groovy
```

I have this in `baseClass.groovy`

```
class BaseClass {
  Integer port = 5000
  String name = null
}
```

and I want to be able to do this in `subClass.groovy`

```
import com.domain.service.baseClass
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  String name = 'myName'
}

def printValues()
  SubClass sc = new SubClass()
  println "Name: $sc.name, Port: $sc.port"
}
```

The idea is I want to define common attributes in my BaseClass and reuse  (e.g. `port`) or override (e.g., `name`) them in my SubClass. You know - OOD. I can have several sub classes all inheriting from BaseClass.

Then in my Jenkins pipeline job config page, I do (I set up 'my-repo' as a shared library in my system configuration)

```
node('linux-node') {
  @library('my-repo')
  def sb = new com.domain.service.subClass()
  sb.printValues()
}
```

When I run this pipeline, I get the following. Does the shared library support this kind of hierarchy?

```
subClass.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class BaseClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `package` definition in class files

```
package com.domain.service
class BaseClass {
  Integer port = 5000
  String name = null
}
```

and

```
package com.domain.service

import com.domain.service.baseClass
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
  String name = 'myName'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i get the same error even when I do this. I'll play with it more.